# ¿Cómo sumar el resultados de los imputs dependiendo de donde se ha introducido un valor?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo esta tabla donde me gustaría mostrar la suma de los valores calculados de acuerdo con el `textbox` donde se están introduciendo los valores.

Es decir que si multiplico quantity por Price el o los valores que aparezcan en importe aparezcan sumados en SUB-Total

Lo mismo si multiplico Quantity por gr, el o los importes sumados aparezcan en GR en la parte inferior y que dada la suma de SUB-Total y GR de el Total.

Por ahora solo he podido sumar las columnas, pero la suma no es correcta ya que omita la multiplicación.

Adjunto el código y espero haber sido claro con el problema que planteo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui adjunto mi código:

```js
 <SCRIPT language="javascript">
 

    function addRow(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        if (rowCount < 10) {
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
            row.id = 'row_' + rowCount;
            for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                newcell.outerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].outerHTML;
            }
            var listitems = row.getElementsByTagName("input")
            for (i = 0; i < listitems.length - 1; i++) {
                listitems[i].setAttribute("oninput", "calculate('" +
                    row.id + "')");
            }
            listitems[listitems.length - 1].setAttribute("onclick", "removeRow('dataTable', " + row.id.replace("row_", "") + ")");
        } else {
            alert("Maximum 10.");

        }
    }


    function removeRow(tableID, index) {
        //Removing the row
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        table.deleteRow(index);
        //Modifying the ids of subsequent rows
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        for (var i = index; i < rowCount; i++) {
            table.rows[i].id = "row_" + i;
            table.rows[i].getElementsByClassName("remove")[0].setAttribute("onclick", "removeRow('dataTable', " + i + ");");
        }
        //Handling the counts
        grandtotal();
    }


    function calculate(elementID) {
        var mainRow = document.getElementById(elementID);
        var myBox1 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[class=qty]')[0].value;
        var myBox2 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[class=cost]')[0].value;
  var myBox3 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[class=gr]')[0].value;
        var total = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[class=subtotal]')[0];
        var myResult1 = myBox1 * (myBox2 + myBox3);
  
        total.value = myResult1;
  
  
  
  
  

        grandtotal();
   
    }

    function grandtotal(){

        //calculation script
        var $form = $('#add_service'),
            $sumDisplay = $('#grand_total');

        var $summands = $form.find('.subtotal');
        var sum = 0;
        $summands.each(function ()
        {
            var value = Number($(this).val());
            if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
        });

        $sumDisplay.val(sum);
    }
 
 
 function sumargr() {

  var total = 0; //inicimos una variable para concatenarle la suma de los inputs

  $(".gr").each(function() { //recorremos el arreglo 

    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) { //con la propiedad this obtenemos el valor del input donde estemos escribiendo y validamos que no sea un número
    //si no lo es agregamos un 0

      total += 0;

    } else {
//si lo es sumamos ese mismo valor
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());

    }

  });

  //agregaos el valor al input que corresponde
  document.getElementById('total_gr').value = total;

}



function sumarcost() {

  var total = 0;

  $(".cost").each(function() {

    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {

      total += 0;

    } else {

      total += parseFloat($(this).val());

    }

  });

  document.getElementById('total_cost').value = total;

}
 
 
 

</script>
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">

    <input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addRow('dataTable')"/>

    <form name="add_name" id="add_service">

        <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
            <tbody>
            <tr id='row_0'>

                <td>
                    <label>Service</label>
                    <input type="text" required="required" name="service[]">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Quantity</label>
                    <input type="number" class="qty"  size="2" name="qty[]" oninput="calculate('row_0')">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="price">Price</label>
                    <input type="text" class="cost" required="required" name="cost[]" oninput="calculate('row_0')" onkeyup="sumarcost()">
                </td>
     <td>
                    <label for="gr">gr</label>
                    <input type="text" class="gr" required="required"  name="gr[]" oninput="calculate('row_0')" onkeyup="sumargr()">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="total">Importe</label>
                    <input type="text" class="subtotal" required="required" readonly name="subtotal[]">

                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="remove" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('dataTable', '0');">
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

  <table>
      
   <tr><td>SUB-Total</td><td><input type="text" class="" placeholder="Total de costos" id="total_cost" readonly></td></tr>
   <tr><td>GR:</td><td><input type="text" class="" placeholder="total gr" id="total_gr" readonly></td></tr>
          <tr><td> Total:</td><td> <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Grand total" id="grand_total" readonly></td></tr>
        

       <tr><td> Crear factura:</td><td> <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit"/></td></tr>
  </table>
    </form>

</div>



</body>
```

Tenga en consideración que las filas son incrementables.

Comment: Yo lo haría de la siguiente manera: como en **importe** ya tengo la multiplicación, si **price** != vacío, a **SUB-Total** le asigno el valor de **importe**. De manera similar lo haría para **GR**.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo comentado las partes que modifiqué con una explicación, espero sea lo que buscas, cualquier duda hazla saber. :)

```js
function addRow(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        if (rowCount < 10) {
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
            row.id = 'row_' + rowCount;
            for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                newcell.outerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].outerHTML;
            }
            var listitems = row.getElementsByTagName("input")
            for (i = 0; i < listitems.length - 1; i++) {
                listitems[i].setAttribute("oninput", "calculate('" +
                    row.id + "')");
            }
            listitems[listitems.length - 1].setAttribute("onclick", "removeRow('dataTable', " + row.id.replace("row_", "") + ")");
        } else {
            alert("Maximum 10.");

        }
    }


    function removeRow(tableID, index) {
        //Removing the row
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        table.deleteRow(index);
        //Modifying the ids of subsequent rows
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        for (var i = index; i < rowCount; i++) {
            table.rows[i].id = "row_" + i;
            table.rows[i].getElementsByClassName("remove")[0].setAttribute("onclick", "removeRow('dataTable', " + i + ");");
        }
        //Handling the counts
        grandtotal();
    }


    function calculate(elementID) {
        var mainRow = document.getElementById(elementID);
        var myBox1 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[class=qty]')[0].value;
        var myBox2 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[class=cost]')[0].value;
  var myBox3 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[class=gr]')[0].value;
        var total = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[class=subtotal]')[0];
        
        //tenías un error estabas concatenando strings, tienes que utilizar parseFloat()
        //o parseInt para convertirlos a números aunque por alguna extraña razón al usar Number no te convertía a número
        var myResult1 = parseFloat(myBox1) * (parseFloat(myBox2) + parseFloat(myBox3));
        
        //validamos que ingrese el número el usuario
        if(isNaN(parseFloat(myBox2)) || isNaN(parseFloat(myBox3))){
        $('#total_cost').val(0);
        $('#total_gr').val(0);
        
        
        }else{
        
        //Si ya ingreso los números se agrega el valor de price multiplicado por quantity
      var qP = parseFloat(myBox1) * parseFloat(myBox2);
          $('#total_cost').val(qP);
          //de igual forma pero con gr
          var qGr = parseFloat(myBox1) * parseFloat(myBox3);
          $('#total_gr').val(qGr);
        
        total.value = myResult1;
  
  
  
  
  

        grandtotal();
   }
    }

    function grandtotal(){

        //calculation script
        var form = $('#add_service'),
            sumDisplay = $('#grand_total');

        var summands = form.find('.subtotal');
        var sum = 0;
        summands.each(function ()
        {
            var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
            if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
        });

        sumDisplay.val(sum);
    }
 
 
 function sumargr() {

  var total = 0; //inicimos una variable para concatenarle la suma de los inputs

  $(".gr").each(function() { //recorremos el arreglo 

    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) { //con la propiedad this obtenemos el valor del input donde estemos escribiendo y validamos que no sea un número
    //si no lo es agregamos un 0

      total += 0;

    } else {
//si lo es sumamos ese mismo valor
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());

    }

  });

  //agregaos el valor al input que corresponde
  document.getElementById('total_gr').value = total;

}



function sumarcost() {

  var total = 0;

  $(".cost").each(function() {

    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {

      total += 0;

    } else {

      total += parseFloat($(this).val());

    }

  });

  document.getElementById('total_cost').value = total;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addRow('dataTable')"/>

    <form name="add_name" id="add_service">

        <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
            <tbody>
            <tr id='row_0'>

                <td>
                    <label>Service</label>
                    <input type="text" required="required" name="service[]">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Quantity</label>
                    <!--LE agregué el atributo min para que solo pueda ingresar del numero 1 en adelante.-->
                    <input type="number" class="qty" min="1" size="2" name="qty[]" oninput="calculate('row_0')">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="price">Price</label>
                    <input type="text" class="cost" required="required" name="cost[]" oninput="calculate('row_0')" onkeyup="sumarcost()">
                </td>
     <td>
                    <label for="gr">gr</label>
                    <input type="text" class="gr" required="required"  name="gr[]" oninput="calculate('row_0')" onkeyup="sumargr()">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="total">Importe</label>
                    <input type="text" class="subtotal" required="required" readonly name="subtotal[]">

                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="remove" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('dataTable', '0');">
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

  <table>
      
   <tr><td>SUB-Total</td><td><input type="text" class="" placeholder="Total de costos" id="total_cost" readonly></td></tr>
   <tr><td>GR:</td><td><input type="text" class="" placeholder="total gr" id="total_gr" readonly></td></tr>
          <tr><td> Total:</td><td> <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Grand total" id="grand_total" readonly></td></tr>
        

       <tr><td> Crear factura:</td><td> <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit"/></td></tr>
  </table>
    </form>

</div>



</body>
```

Comment: Hola vick, los valores de la multiplicacion no aparecen en el input importe y los imput GR Y SUB-TOTAL tampoco aparecen los valores