# Text box no suman en javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

tengo este código donde simulo un creador de factura.
también tiene un boton donde se añade mas filas para poder añadirle elementos naturales a una factura.
Los campos total_gr y total_cost deben sumare y mostrar el resultado en grand_total. 
El problema radica cuando añado el código que está arriba del div ,     div class="container"   algún elemento del código no me está permitiendo sumar las clases, pero, cuando quito el código arriba de la clase div class="container" las clases  total_gr y total_cost si muestran el resultado en el id id="grand_total"

```js
    function addRow(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        if (rowCount < 10) {
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
            row.id = 'row_' + rowCount;
            for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                newcell.outerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].outerHTML;
            }
            var listitems = row.getElementsByTagName("input")
            for (i = 0; i < listitems.length - 1; i++) {
                listitems[i].setAttribute("oninput", "calculate('" +
                    row.id + "')");
            }
            listitems[listitems.length - 1].setAttribute("onclick", "removeRow('dataTable', " + row.id.replace("row_", "") + ")");
        } else {
            alert("Maximum 10.");

        }
    }


    function removeRow(tableID, index) {
        //Removing the row
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        table.deleteRow(index);
        //Modifying the ids of subsequent rows
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        for (var i = index; i < rowCount; i++) {
            table.rows[i].id = "row_" + i;
            table.rows[i].getElementsByClassName("remove")[0].setAttribute("onclick", "removeRow('dataTable', " + i + ");");
        }
        //Handling the counts
        grandtotal();
    }


    function calculate(elementID) {
        var mainRow = document.getElementById(elementID);
        var myBox1 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[class=qty]')[0].value;
        var myBox2 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[class=cost]')[0].value;
  var myBox3 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[class=gr]')[0].value;
        var total = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[class=subtotal]')[0];
        var myResult1 = myBox1 * (myBox2 + myBox3);
  
        total.value = myResult1;
  
  
  
  
  

        grandtotal();
   
    }

    function grandtotal(){

        //calculation script
        var $form = $('#add_service'),
            $sumDisplay = $('#grand_total');

        var $summands = $form.find('.subtotal');
        var sum = 0;
        $summands.each(function ()
        {
            var value = Number($(this).val());
            if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
        });

        $sumDisplay.val(sum);
    }
 
 
 function sumargr() {

  var total = 0; //inicimos una variable para concatenarle la suma de los inputs

  $(".gr").each(function() { //recorremos el arreglo 

    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) { //con la propiedad this obtenemos el valor del input donde estemos escribiendo y validamos que no sea un número
    //si no lo es agregamos un 0

      total += 0;

    } else {
//si lo es sumamos ese mismo valor
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());

    }

  });

  //agregaos el valor al input que corresponde
  document.getElementById('total_gr').value = total;

}



function sumarcost() {

  var total = 0;

  $(".cost").each(function() {

    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {

      total += 0;

    } else {

      total += parseFloat($(this).val());

    }

  });

  document.getElementById('total_cost').value = total;

}
```

```html
<body>

<h1>Creación de factura</h1>
 
 <form action="pfactura.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <fieldset>
     <legend>Seleccione un cliente y luego presiona buscar:</legend>
   <?php
$result = mysqli_query($connex,"SELECT * FROM clientes ORDER by nomcli desc");
 $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);//contar resultados totales     
?> 
 
     <td><select name="nomcli" id="nomcli">  
                <option value="-" selected="selected">Seleccione un cliente</option>  
                <?php
    $sqnomape = "SELECT * FROM clientes ";
   $renomape = mysqli_query($connex, $sqnomape);
   if (mysqli_num_rows($renomape) > 0) {
//Condición para validar si un registro ya existe.
   while($rownomape = mysqli_fetch_assoc($renomape)) {

   
?>
               <option value='<?php echo $rownomape["nomcli"]; ?>' required> <?php echo  $rownomape["nomcli"]; ?>  </option>
                <?php  
    }
   }
  ?> 
              </select></td>
  
  
  <input name="buscar" type="submit" name="buscar" value="buscar" title="Buscar." />

 
   </fieldset>
</form>
 <?php
 $nomcli2 = $_POST['nomcli'];//Nombre del cliente
 
    ?>
 
 
 <form action="pfactura2.php" autocomplete="off" method="post">
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Llene los campos para crear la factura.</legend><fieldset>
   
 <?php  ?>
 
   <?php
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nomcli = '$nomcli2'";
$result = mysqli_query($connex, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 ?>
   <table width="auto" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Nombre del cliente</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="nomcli" readonly value="<?php echo $row["nomcli"]; ?>"></td>
   <td>Limite de crédito:<input type="text" readonly size="10" value="<?php echo $row["licred"]; ?>"></td>
  
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Código del cliente</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="codcli" readonly value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"></td>
  <td>Fecha de facturación: <input type="date" name="fech" required ></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Dirección</td>
      <td><input type="text" readonly value="<?php echo $row["dir"]; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tel:</td>
      <td><input type="text" readonly size="10" value="<?php echo $row["tel"]; ?>">Cel:<input type="text" readonly size="10" value="<?php echo $row["cel"]; ?>"></td>
   
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Acarreo:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="acarreo" size="50"></td>
    <td rowspan="3"><textarea placeholder="Comentario"rows="4" cols="50" name="coment" >
</textarea></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Desde:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="desde" size="50"></td>
   
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Hacia:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="hacia" size="50" ></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
   

 <div class="container">

    <input type="button" value="Añadir fila" onClick="addRow('dataTable')"/>

    <form name="add_name" id="add_service">

        <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
            <tbody>
            <tr id='row_0'>

                <td>
                    <label>Service</label>
                    <input type="text"  name="service[]">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Quantity</label>
                    <input type="text" class="qty" value="1" size="5" readonly name="qty[]" oninput="calculate('row_0')">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="price">Price</label>
                    <input type="text" class="cost"  name="cost[]" oninput="calculate('row_0')" onkeyup="sumarcost()">
                </td>
     <td>
                    <label for="gr">gr</label>
                    <input type="text" class="gr"   name="gr[]" oninput="calculate('row_0')" onkeyup="sumargr()">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="total">Importe</label>
                    <input type="text" class="subtotal"  readonly name="subtotal[]">

                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="remove" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('dataTable', '0');">
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

  <table>
      
   <tr><td>SUB-Total</td><td><input type="text" class="" placeholder="Total de costos" id="total_cost" readonly></td></tr>
   <tr><td>GR:</td><td><input type="text" class="" placeholder="total gr" id="total_gr" readonly></td></tr>
          <tr><td> Total:</td><td> <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Grand total" id="grand_total" readonly></td></tr>
        

       <tr><td> Crear factura:</td><td> <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit"/></td></tr>
  </table>
    </form>

</div>
   
   
<?php 
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
   
?>
   
   

</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Te refieres al código de PHP para crear tu tabla?

Comment: el código que está arriba del div div class="container" tiene algo que no permite que debajo lo demas sume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código funciona cuando eliminas la parte de `PHP + MySQLi` porque tienes error al momento de imprimir tus variables `PHP`, recuerda si vas a imprimir una variable `PHP` dentro de un atributo `HTML` en este caso el `value=""` si utilizas comillas dobles `" "` entonces el `índice` de tu variable tiene que ir con comillas simples `' '` o viceversa, en caso de utilizar un `índice numérico` este iría sin comillas ni dobles ni simples. Ejemplo: `value="<?php echo $row['nomcli'];?>"` o  `value='<?php echo $row["nomcli"];?>'`

En caso de usar `indice numérico`: `value="<?php echo $row[0];?>"`

```js
function addRow(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        if (rowCount < 10) {
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
            row.id = 'row_' + rowCount;
            for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                newcell.outerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].outerHTML;
            }
            var listitems = row.getElementsByTagName("input")
            for (i = 0; i < listitems.length - 1; i++) {
                listitems[i].setAttribute("oninput", "calculate('" +
                    row.id + "')");
            }
            listitems[listitems.length - 1].setAttribute("onclick", "removeRow('dataTable', " + row.id.replace("row_", "") + ")");
        } else {
            alert("Maximum 10.");

        }
    }


    function removeRow(tableID, index) {
        //Removing the row
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        table.deleteRow(index);
        //Modifying the ids of subsequent rows
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        for (var i = index; i < rowCount; i++) {
            table.rows[i].id = "row_" + i;
            table.rows[i].getElementsByClassName("remove")[0].setAttribute("onclick", "removeRow('dataTable', " + i + ");");
        }
        //Handling the counts
        grandtotal();
    }


    function calculate(elementID) {
        var mainRow = document.getElementById(elementID);
        var myBox1 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[class=qty]')[0].value;
        var myBox2 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[class=cost]')[0].value;
  var myBox3 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[class=gr]')[0].value;
        var total = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[class=subtotal]')[0];
        var myResult1 = myBox1 * (myBox2 + myBox3);
  
        total.value = myResult1;
  
  
  
  
  

        grandtotal();
   
    }

    function grandtotal(){

        //calculation script
        var $form = $('#add_service'),
            $sumDisplay = $('#grand_total');

        var $summands = $form.find('.subtotal');
        var sum = 0;
        $summands.each(function ()
        {
            var value = Number($(this).val());
            if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
        });

        $sumDisplay.val(sum);
    }
 
 
 function sumargr() {

  var total = 0; //inicimos una variable para concatenarle la suma de los inputs

  $(".gr").each(function() { //recorremos el arreglo 

    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) { //con la propiedad this obtenemos el valor del input donde estemos escribiendo y validamos que no sea un número
    //si no lo es agregamos un 0

      total += 0;

    } else {
//si lo es sumamos ese mismo valor
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());

    }

  });

  //agregaos el valor al input que corresponde
  document.getElementById('total_gr').value = total;

}



function sumarcost() {

  var total = 0;

  $(".cost").each(function() {

    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {

      total += 0;

    } else {

      total += parseFloat($(this).val());

    }

  });

  document.getElementById('total_cost').value = total;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h1>Creación de factura</h1>
 
 <form action="pfactura.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <fieldset>
     <legend>Seleccione un cliente y luego presiona buscar:</legend>
   <?php
$result = mysqli_query($connex,"SELECT * FROM clientes ORDER by nomcli desc");
 $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);//contar resultados totales     
?> 
 
     <td><select name="nomcli" id="nomcli">  
                <option value="-" selected="selected">Seleccione un cliente</option>  
                <?php
    $sqnomape = "SELECT * FROM clientes ";
   $renomape = mysqli_query($connex, $sqnomape);
   if (mysqli_num_rows($renomape) > 0) {
//Condición para validar si un registro ya existe.
   while($rownomape = mysqli_fetch_assoc($renomape)) {

   
?>
               <option value='<?php echo $rownomape["nomcli"]; ?>' required> <?php echo  $rownomape["nomcli"]; ?>  </option>
                <?php  
    }
   }
  ?> 
              </select></td>
  
  
  <input name="buscar" type="submit" name="buscar" value="buscar" title="Buscar." />

 
   </fieldset>
</form>
 <?php
 $nomcli2 = $_POST['nomcli'];//Nombre del cliente
 
    ?>
 
 
 <form action="pfactura2.php" autocomplete="off" method="post">
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Llene los campos para crear la factura.</legend><fieldset>
   
 <?php  ?>
 
   <?php
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nomcli = '$nomcli2'";
$result = mysqli_query($connex, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    //output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 ?>
   <table width="auto" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Nombre del cliente</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="nomcli" readonly value="<?php echo $row['nomcli']; ?>"></td>
   <td>Limite de crédito:<input type="text" readonly size="10" value="<?php echo $row['licred']; ?>"></td>
  
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Código del cliente</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="codcli" readonly value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"></td>
  <td>Fecha de facturación: <input type="date" name="fech" required ></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Dirección</td>
      <td><input type="text" readonly value="<?php echo $row['dir']; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tel:</td>
      <td><input type="text" readonly size="10" value="<?php echo $row['tel']; ?>">Cel:<input type="text" readonly size="10" value="<?php echo $row['cel']; ?>"></td>
   
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Acarreo:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="acarreo" size="50"></td>
    <td rowspan="3"><textarea placeholder="Comentario"rows="4" cols="50" name="coment" >
</textarea></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Desde:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="desde" size="50"></td>
   
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Hacia:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="hacia" size="50" ></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>   

 <div class="container">

    <input type="button" value="Añadir fila" onClick="addRow('dataTable')"/>

    <form name="add_name" id="add_service">

        <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
            <tbody>
            <tr id='row_0'>

                <td>
                    <label>Service</label>
                    <input type="text"  name="service[]">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Quantity</label>
                    <input type="text" class="qty" value="1" size="5" readonly name="qty[]" oninput="calculate('row_0')">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="price">Price</label>
                    <input type="text" class="cost"  name="cost[]" oninput="calculate('row_0')" onkeyup="sumarcost()">
                </td>
     <td>
                    <label for="gr">gr</label>
                    <input type="text" class="gr"   name="gr[]" oninput="calculate('row_0')" onkeyup="sumargr()">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="total">Importe</label>
                    <input type="text" class="subtotal"  readonly name="subtotal[]">

                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="remove" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('dataTable', '0');">
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

  <table>
      
   <tr><td>SUB-Total</td><td><input type="text" class="" placeholder="Total de costos" id="total_cost" readonly></td></tr>
   <tr><td>GR:</td><td><input type="text" class="" placeholder="total gr" id="total_gr" readonly></td></tr>
          <tr><td> Total:</td><td> <input type="text" class="" placeholder="Grand total" id="grand_total" readonly></td></tr>
        

       <tr><td> Crear factura:</td><td> <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit"/></td></tr>
  </table>
    </form>

</div>
  
   
<?php 
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
   
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Vick me has salvado, tengo mas proyectos pendientes quiero poder comunicarte contigo y pagarte, como hacemos?

Comment: No hay de qué, y para nada mi estimado, lo hago para apoyar a la comunidad, cualquiera de nosotros te puede ayudar sin motivos de lucro. :D